# Как остановить выполнение кода из метода?

Tags: c#, wpf

Ставлю в коде return а программа выполняется далее.
Как ее остановить чтобы дальше код не выполнялся?

```cs
private void inputValidationLogin ()
{

    string login = textBoxLogin.Text.Trim();
    if ( login.Length == 0 )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("В ведите данные для авторизации в ФБ");
    }
    return;


}


private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

  inputValidationLogin();
  MessageBox.Show("А я работаю далее, хотя не должна ...");
            
}
```

Comment: @ΝNL993  Environment.Exit(0); Закрывает программу. А я хочу остановить просто чтобы дальше ничего не выполнялось.

Comment: по-хорошему, валидация должна либо возвращать true/false и на основе этого программа будет реагировать как вам нужно, либо кидать исключение и вызывающий код ловить его

Comment: Вы можете использовать флаги bool и возвращать из значение если что то пошло не по плану, например 
`if(true)`
return;
что то вроде того, вы сможете останавливать выполнение метода. Используя return вы возвращаете метода, string или же void и т.п. То есть return не останавливает выполнение кода.

Comment: Если вы хотите останавливать выполнение потоков\методов на уровне программы вы можете ознакомиться с этим https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.5.php

Comment: ` MessageBox.Show("А я работаю далее, хотя не должна ...");` вы присвоили `messageText = "В ведите данные для авторизации в ФБ";` То есть `if (loginRez != "")` уже не равно `""` не понятно что вы этим примером хотели показать.  А целом возвращая методы  и обрабатывая их значения только там можно обработать код каком либо месте, если нужно полностью прекратить выполнение, то по ссылке выше показано как это сделать. Например можно написать метод который отменяет задачу, и если условие не верно, вызывать метод для отмены задачи.

Comment: _Я откатил правку с добавлением ответа в текст вопроса. Еслу вас появилось решение - опубликуйте его как ответ в форме ответа ниже._